# Update parameter depending on callback and pass the updated parameter in the loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

Y have a loop that executes a function with a callback to grab a result. Currently I have this code but I cannot figure out how to pass the correct parameterUpdated as parameter to the function for every iteration. It remains the same.I cannot put the update() function outside the callback because as you see it depends on the result variable, which is only visible into the callback scope. Is there any way to pass the correct value of parameterUpdated?

```
var parameterUpdated=[];
...
while(j<value)
{
    (function(j){
       doSomething(parameterUpdated, function(result){
          parameterUpdated=parameterUpdated.filter(function(element){/*array filter that involves "result" and "j" variables*/});  //I want to pass filtered array to the next iteration loop but only changes from outer scope.
       });
      })(j);
      j++;
}
```

Comment: Your code fragment doesn't make much sense as it is, particularly regarding the focus of your question (`parameterUpdated`) since it's not clear what value it holds or what transitions it goes through. Please provide a "real use case".

Comment: @Amit thanks, I have tried to provide more concrete details.

Comment: Is `doSomething` asynchronous?

Comment: This just doesn't look like it's constructed correctly. As @JLRishe hinted, if doSomething is async, it's probably not doing what you think it does, and doesn't wokr. If it's not, there's no justification to go through all this callback hell